# Data transfer via ModBustcp

Tags: python, modbus

I wrote a simple server to check data transfer via ModBusTcp and threw it on another device with ip 192.168.43.103. However, the server starts up and immediately shuts down. I don't even know why, can someone help please? I checked on my PC with ip 192.168.43.102, of course changed the ip to my pc's ip in the code and it worked fine.
Below is the code I am running on the second device

```
from pyModbusTCP.server import ModbusServer
from time import sleep

# Create an instance of ModbusServer
server = ModbusServer("192.168.43.103", 502, no_block=True)

try:
    print("Start server...")
    server.start()
    print("Server is online")
    state = [0, 0]
    while True:
        # Read input from user
        reg0 = int(input("Enter value for Register 0: "))
        reg1 = int(input("Enter value for Register 1: "))

        # Write to DataBank
        server.data_bank.set_holding_registers(0, [reg0])
        server.data_bank.set_holding_registers(1, [reg1])

        # Check if state has changed
        if state != server.data_bank.get_holding_registers(1):
            state = server.data_bank.get_holding_registers(1)
            print("Value of Register 1 has changed to " + str(state[0]))

        sleep(0.5)

except:
    print("Shutdown server...")
    server.stop()
    print("Server is offline")
```

[image]

Comment: Try to add exception handling block to your code